# Specific logo on other page in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am looking for a css solution for my Wordpress website http://www.praktijkvanginkel.nl/new/. It is running the Avada theme.

On all pages except 1, the normal logo shows as usual. On the exception page ( http://praktijkvanginkel.nl/new/huid-vitaal/), I need a different logo.

What I tried: Using page-id in css to replace the original logo with the new one. The problem: the old logo still shows under the new one. I have applied the following css:

```
.page-id-90 #header .fusion-logo img a{
display: none !important
}

.page-id-90 .fusion-footer-copyright-area {
background-color: #ff008e!important;
border-color: #4b4c4d;
border-top-width: 1px;
padding-top: 18px;
padding-bottom: 16px;
}

body.page-id-90 .fusion-logo img {
background: url('http://praktijkvanginkel.nl/new/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/huidvitaal.png') top left no-repeat !important;
display: block !important;
height: 85px !important;
width: 212px !important;
}


body.page-id-90 .fusion-logo .fusion-logo-2x {
display: none!important;
}

.page-id-90 .fusion-is-sticky .fusion-logo img {
background: url('http://praktijkvanginkel.nl/new/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/huidvitaal.png') top left no-repeat !important;
display: block !important;
height: 52px !important;
width: 129px !important;
}
```

I just cannot figure out why the old logo is still there. Can anyone help me with this? I would also appreciate a solution for the sticky header logo, which has the same problem

Comment: Why are you applying an image as a background to an `img` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is not the best solution for doing this...However, since you asked, you can apply the background to the link tag instead of the image tag:

```
body.page-id-90 .fusion-logo-link img {
    display: none;
}
body.page-id-90 .fusion-logo-link {
    background: url('../2016/06/huidvitaal.png') no-repeat top left;
    display: block;
    height: 85px;
    width: 212px;
}
```

None of the other code you shared is necessary to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in CSS only, how about changing the image opacity to 0 and adding the background image to the logo link instead?

```
body.page-id-90 a.fusion-logo-link {
    background: url('http://praktijkvanginkel.nl/new/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/huidvitaal.png') top left no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

body.page-id-90 .fusion-logo img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Setting the background size for the link should also fix your sticky header problem too. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, I think the logo is hardcoded in your index.php file

```
<img src="//praktijkvanginkel.nl/new/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/praktijkvanginkel-1.png"...
<img src="//praktijkvanginkel.nl/new/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/praktijkvanginkel-1.png"...
```

You could delete this lines, dont forget to make a backup of this lines if its not working.

Then in your CSS-File you could add:

```
.fusion-logo img {background: url('../2016/06/praktijkvanginkel-1.png')...
.page-id-90 .fusion-logo img {background: url('../2016/06/huidvitaal.png')...
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code in header or footer.php file.

`<?php if(is_page( 'huid-vitaal' )){ ?>
       jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         $('.fusion-logo .fusion-logo-link img').attr('src','second.jpg');
        });
   <?php } ?>`